Movie/TV-series about a woman finding her husband wounded in their house
I'm looking for a movie (or series) and it's told by a woman's point of view. I think that woman has some connection to some agents. She also has a spouse, who has brown hair and circular glasses. The man is a teacher. I remember that he teaches the Spanish language. But I'm not sure.
I remember a particular scene describing the couple's joint home. The living room has a lot of helium balloons and they say that the baby is a boy/girl (It's a boy! -like that). The woman comes home and assumes that her husband is okay, because he's sitting in the kitchen chair. He isn't okay. He bleeds. Then an outside man will come around the corner (or out of the shadows) and commands the woman to sit down. They discuss until the outside man hits a knife into the side of the husband and then walks away. The woman washes the carpet, which was full of the blood of her husband, and then she finds a hiding place under the floorboards. There was a wooden box with a similar pattern as the fire scar which she has on her hand. Inside that wooden box she found false passports and a different currency.

That's the first episode of The Blacklist.
The woman, Elizabeth Keen, is an FBI profiler. On her first day on the job, one of the most wanted criminals, Raymond Reddington, turns himself in and offers information on criminals the FBI doesn't even know about.
His most important condition is talking to Elizabeth Keen exclusively.
The scene you remember is half way through the first episode. Elizabeth Keen and her husband Tom were in the process of adopting a baby. Tom had decorated the living room to celebrate.
The bad guy of the week assaults him, ties him to chair to wait for Elizabeth's arrival, then, after talking to Elizabeth, stabs him and gets away.  
While cleaning the blood stains, she pulls up the carpet and discovers a box hidden under the floor, containing passports with her husbands picture but under different aliases, money in different currencies, and a gun, confirming Reddington's warning that there is more to her husband than meets the eye.

Questions about the series on this site are tagged with the-blacklist.

Adding my version of the answer since the first answer doesn't explain why this is the correct answer and my suggested edit is too long...
You're describing the pilot of 'The Blacklist'.
From IMDB:

Elizabeth heads home to clear her head only to discover that her husband has been bound and gagged and tortured. Zamani is in her house with a gun. He says to do what he says or he'll shoot her husband. (Incidentally, they were approved for the adoption. It's a girl.) Zamani says he was done with the chemist so they saved him payment. Zamani asks what else she knows about his plan. She says they've speculated about a bomb but that is all. Zamani stabs Tom in the thigh. .......The FBI investigates Liz's house. After the CSU leave she tries to scrub the blood out of the carpet and discovers a secret cubbyhole under the floorboards. It is full of money, guns, and a half dozen fake passports. 

